# How to save a select query result in a variable?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm working in a flask app and, like title suggests, I want to save a 'select query result' (sqlite db) in a variable like this:

```
id_ = g.db.execute("SELECT id_user FROM user WHERE name = ?", [username])
```

but it doesn't work fine. How can I do?

Comment: You should explain "doesn't work". That could mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`.fetch*()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id19) to get results.

If you're confident you're only going to get one result, you can do:

```
id_ = g.db.execute("SELECT id_user FROM user WHERE name = ?", [username]).fetchone()[0]
```

Edit: Need to add a `[0]` at the end since the `fetch*()` methods always return a sequence. Even though the query only returns one item, it's still a sequence with a single item, so to set `id_` to it, assign it to the first (and only) item in the result sequence.

Comment: Added: Need to add a `[0]` at the end since the `fetch*()` methods always return a sequence. Even though the query only returns one item, it's still a sequence.